# ctypes.cast always throw ArgumentError

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have the following code

```
 from ctypes import cast, c_char_p, c_int, byref, POINTER

 # ...
 mj, mn, pt = c_int(), c_int(), c_int()
 // FreeType
 __dll__.FT_Library_Version(__handler__, byref(mj), byref(mn), byref(pt))

 print("{0}.{1}.{2}".format(cast(mj, POINTER(c_char_p).value, cast(mn, POINTER(c_char_p).value, cast(pt, POINTER(c_char_p)).value)
```

throw a `ArgumentError` from `cast` function `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`

the question is why? where is the error in my code i'm a newbiew with ctypes but i find examples like `cast(c_int, POINTER(c_char_p))` for pŕint `c_int` without get a `c_int(2)`

Comment: The first argument to cast is supposed to be an object, not a type.

Comment: sorry was a error while is writing the question. i'll fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The cast() function can be used to cast a ctypes instance into a 
>   pointer to a different ctypes data type. cast() takes two parameters,
>   a ctypes object **that is or can be converted to a pointer** of some
>   kind, and a ctypes pointer type. It returns an instance of the second
>   argument, which references the same memory block as the first argument.

I think you just want to do this:

```
print("%d.%d.%d"%(mj.value,mn.value,pt.value))
```

Comment: Ok how to convert c_int into int python or string